# Python compiled code crashes

Tags: py2exe

I made this game in python 2.7 and it worked in .py format but when I compiled it with py2exe it suddenly broke. It gave me this error:

"Microsoft Visuak C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!
Program C:\Python27\Helmetdodger\Stuffz\main.exe
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the program's support team."

The code:

```
import pygame
import random, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 1200
WINDOWHEIGHT = 900
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 40
BADDIEMINSIZE = 10
BADDIEMAXSIZE = 40
BADDIEMINSPEED = 1
BADDIEMAXSPEED = 8
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 6
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    os.exit(1)

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    for b in baddies:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Helmetdodger')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')

# set up images
playerImage1 = pygame.image.load('player1.png')
powerImage = pygame.image.load('power.png')
playerRect = playerImage1.get_rect()
baddieImage1 = pygame.image.load('baddie.png')
baddieImage2 = pygame.image.load('baddie1.png')
baddieImage3 = pygame.image.load('baddie2.png')
baddieImage4 = pygame.image.load('baddie3.png')
baddieImage5 = pygame.image.load('baddie4.png')
baddieImage6 = pygame.image.load('baddie5.png')
baddieImage7 = pygame.image.load('baddie6.png')
baddieImage8 = pygame.image.load('baddie7.png')
baddieImage9 = pygame.image.load('baddie8.png')
baddieImage10 = pygame.image.load('baddie9.png')
baddieImage11 = pygame.image.load('baddie10.png')
baddieImage12 = pygame.image.load('baddie11.png')
baddieImage13 = pygame.image.load('baddie12.png')
baddieImage14 = pygame.image.load('baddie13.png')
baddieImage15 = pygame.image.load('baddie14.png')
baddieImage16 = pygame.image.load('baddie15.png')
baddieImage17 = pygame.image.load('baddie16.png')
baddieImage18 = pygame.image.load('baddie17.png')
baddieImage19 = pygame.image.load('baddie18.png')
baddieImage20 = pygame.image.load('baddie19.png')
baddieImage21 = pygame.image.load('baddie20.png')
baddieImage22 = pygame.image.load('baddie21.png')
baddieImage23 = pygame.image.load('baddie22.png')
baddieImage24 = pygame.image.load('baddie23.png')
baddieImage25 = pygame.image.load('baddie24.png')
baddieImage26 = pygame.image.load('baddie25.png')
baddieImage27 = pygame.image.load('baddie26.png')
baddieImage28 = pygame.image.load('baddie27.png')
baddieImage29 = pygame.image.load('baddie28.png')
baddieImage30 = pygame.image.load('baddie29.png')
baddieImages = [baddieImage1, baddieImage2, baddieImage3, baddieImage4, baddieImage5, baddieImage6, baddieImage7, baddieImage8, baddieImage9, baddieImage10, baddieImage11, baddieImage12, baddieImage13, baddieImage14, baddieImage15, baddieImage16, baddieImage17, baddieImage18, baddieImage19, baddieImage20, baddieImage21, baddieImage22, baddieImage23, baddieImage24, baddieImage25, baddieImage26, baddieImage27, baddieImage28, baddieImage29, baddieImage20]

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Helmetdodger', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

#Get highscore
topScore = 0
try:
    file = open('hs.txt', "r")
    topScore = file.read()
    topScore = int(topScore)
    file.close()
except:
    topScore = 0

while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    baddies = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    baddieAddCounter = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
    powerCount = 0

    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        # Add new baddies at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            baddieAddCounter += 1
        if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
            baddieCount = random.randrange(len(baddieImages))
            baddieAddCounter = 0
            baddieSize = random.randint(BADDIEMINSIZE, BADDIEMAXSIZE)
            newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                        'speed': random.randint(BADDIEMINSPEED, BADDIEMAXSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImages[baddieCount], (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                        }

            baddies.append(newBaddie)



        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        # Move the baddies down.
        for b in baddies:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

         # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in baddies[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                baddies.remove(b)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage1, playerRect)

        # Draw each baddie
        for b in baddies:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if any of the baddies have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score
                file = open("hs.txt", "w")
                score = str(score)
                file.write(score)
                file.close()
            break

        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()

    drawText('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: Have you tested your program [before bundling it up into an EXE](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step1)? Do you know [how py2exe works](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ)?

Comment: Before compiled it works (in .py format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My buildscript was incorrect, I found a better buildscript online to use instead

```
try:
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe, pygame
    from modulefinder import Module
    import glob, fnmatch
    import sys, os, shutil
    import operator
except ImportError, message:
    raise SystemExit,  "Unable to load module. %s" % message

#hack which fixes the pygame mixer and pygame font
origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL # save the orginal before we edit it
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
    # checks if the freetype and ogg dll files are being included
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ("libfreetype-6.dll", "libogg-0.dll","sdl_ttf.dll"): # "sdl_ttf.dll" added by arit.
            return 0
    return origIsSystemDLL(pathname) # return the orginal function
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL # override the default function with this one

class pygame2exe(py2exe.build_exe.py2exe): #This hack make sure that pygame default font is copied: no need to modify code for specifying default font
    def copy_extensions(self, extensions):
        #Get pygame default font
        pygamedir = os.path.split(pygame.base.__file__)[0]
        pygame_default_font = os.path.join(pygamedir, pygame.font.get_default_font())

        #Add font to list of extension to be copied
        extensions.append(Module("pygame.font", pygame_default_font))
        py2exe.build_exe.py2exe.copy_extensions(self, extensions)

class BuildExe:
    def __init__(self):
        #Name of starting + .py
        self.script = "raw.py"

        #Name of program
        self.project_name = "main"

        #Project url
        self.project_url = "about:none"

        #Version of program
        self.project_version = "0.0"

        #License of the program
        self.license = "MyApps License"

        #Auhor of program
        self.author_name = "Me"
        self.author_email = "example@example.com"
        self.copyright = "Copyright (c) 2009 Me."

        #Description
        self.project_description = "MyApps Description"

        #Icon file (None will use pygame default icon)
        self.icon_file = None

        #Extra files/dirs copied to game
        self.extra_datas = []

        #Extra/excludes python modules
        self.extra_modules = []
        self.exclude_modules = []

        #DLL Excludes
        self.exclude_dll = ['']
        #python scripts (strings) to be included, seperated by a comma
        self.extra_scripts = []

        #Zip file name (None will bundle files in exe instead of zip file)
        self.zipfile_name = None

        #Dist directory
        self.dist_dir ='C:\Python27\dist'

    ## Code from DistUtils tutorial at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial
    ## Originally borrowed from wxPython's setup and config files
    def opj(self, *args):
        path = os.path.join(*args)
        return os.path.normpath(path)

    def find_data_files(self, srcdir, *wildcards, **kw):
        # get a list of all files under the srcdir matching wildcards,
        # returned in a format to be used for install_data
        def walk_helper(arg, dirname, files):
            if '.svn' in dirname:
                return
            names = []
            lst, wildcards = arg
            for wc in wildcards:
                wc_name = self.opj(dirname, wc)
                for f in files:
                    filename = self.opj(dirname, f)

                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, wc_name) and not os.path.isdir(filename):
                        names.append(filename)
            if names:
                lst.append( (dirname, names ) )

        file_list = []
        recursive = kw.get('recursive', True)
        if recursive:
            os.path.walk(srcdir, walk_helper, (file_list, wildcards))
        else:
            walk_helper((file_list, wildcards),
                        srcdir,
                        [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(self.opj(srcdir, '*'))])
        return file_list

    def run(self):
        if os.path.isdir(self.dist_dir): #Erase previous destination dir
            shutil.rmtree(self.dist_dir)

        #Use the default pygame icon, if none given
        if self.icon_file == None:
            path = os.path.split(pygame.__file__)[0]
            self.icon_file = os.path.join(path, 'pygame.ico')

        #List all data files to add
        extra_datas = []
        for data in self.extra_datas:
            if os.path.isdir(data):
                extra_datas.extend(self.find_data_files(data, '*'))
            else:
                extra_datas.append(('.', [data]))

        setup(
            cmdclass = {'py2exe': pygame2exe},
            version = self.project_version,
            description = self.project_description,
            name = self.project_name,
            url = self.project_url,
            author = self.author_name,
            author_email = self.author_email,
            license = self.license,

            # targets to build
            windows = [{
                'script': self.script,
                'icon_resources': [(0, self.icon_file)],
                'copyright': self.copyright
            }],
            options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2, 'bundle_files': 2, 'compressed': True, \
                                  'excludes': self.exclude_modules, 'packages': self.extra_modules, \
                                  'dll_excludes': self.exclude_dll,
                                  'includes': self.extra_scripts} },
            zipfile = self.zipfile_name,
            data_files = extra_datas,
            dist_dir = self.dist_dir
            )

        if os.path.isdir('build'): #Clean up build dir
            shutil.rmtree('build')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if operator.lt(len(sys.argv), 2):
        sys.argv.append('py2exe')
    BuildExe().run() #Run generation
    raw_input("Press any key to continue") #Pause to let user see that things ends
```